# What calculus material can prepare me for MCMC?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, stochastic-calculus, book-recommendation, monte-carlo

I am looking to revise calculus from scratch to move on to Monte Carlo Markov Chain Methods and Quasi Monte Carlo Methods. I studied calculus properly a couple of years ago however it was back in high school and I'd like more thorough foundation.

Can anyone suggest any texts I can look at, be it online or books? I would like to look at some of the theoretical work but also with a heavy emphasis on problems that I can work out.

This looks like it could give me a good introduction, LV Tarasov's Calculus: Concepts for High School,  but I'm not sure if it's enough to prepare me for MCMC methods.

Comment: For me, the one true calculus book will always be Spivak.

Comment: If we're talking about the one true calculus book it has to be A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis, John L Bell.

Comment: I've seen reviews online on these 2 and they both look great but it seems they rely a lot on proofs too, do they have plenty of exercises where I can workout integrals, differentials and so forth?